# Is there a way to mirror Gitlab's built in bug-tracking content?

Tags: gitlab, bug-tracking, mirroring

We've started using a private Gitlab installation for project management (Git, Bug-tracking and so on). I know it's fairly trivial to share out or mirror the Git repos, but what about the Issue Tracking content?

I see Gitlab offers a fairly involved and tedious method to manually back up and restore a Gitlab installation, but I'm looking for close to real time mirroring in case of hard drive failure or other catastrophes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repositories can be easily mirrored using Git protocol. Other types of data in GitLab are stored in the database and can't be mirrored in the same way.

Using a good old backup and restore process is probably the best solution for the situation you described. GitLab has this documented at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html. The process really isn't that difficult - `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` to create a backup, and `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=<timestamp>` to restore.

If you need a higher level of service, GitLab supports high availability - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/high_availability/

Comment: Agreed, I did see the backup and restore thing, but as I stated, I'm looking for a mirror method, not a manual method. I will have a few dozen projects in Git repos soon (moving things from SVN) and I have no time to manually back up and restore them on a daily basis. Manual is not scaleable.

Comment: You probably don't even need to restore/have a mirror at all. Use the backup method so you have a way to restore in the event of a failure. The backup task can automatically upload to object storage, or even just copy to a different mounted disk/network file store. Put the backup task on a cron. These are about your only options short of full-on HA.

Comment: I'll likely end up cron scripting this as you suggest, perhaps restoring to a mirror with cron as well, as I've not discovered any other method to solve this. We host on our own internal server(s) - we have a cloud provider who suddenly doubled the subscription price recently, once you're all in on a proprietary bug tracker on a cloud platform they have you over a barrel.